# Dataclass not instantiating variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

```
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Test:

    ts=time.time()


while 1:
    m = Test()
    print(m.ts)
    time.sleep(2)
```

With this code, I would expect the time to be increasing by 2 every time, but it is staying constant. How can I get the time to refresh everytime the dataclass is instantiated?

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: ts isn't a dataclass field here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an *instance* attribute, not a class attribute, that gets initialized to the current time. Use `dataclasses.field` to configure the class to use a default factory to define the `ts` field if no explicit value is given on instantiation.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import time


@dataclass
class Test:
    ts: float = field(default_factory=time.time)
```

Then you can use the default

```
>>> Test().ts
1654541245.673183
```

or provide an explicit timestamp (for testing, if nothing else)

```
>>> Test(3.14159).ts
3.14159
```